# Why can't I access my url_helpers from my development database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a file located in my rails app with this path: `lib/reverification/template.rb`

Here is a snippet of the contents of this file:

```
module Reverification
   class Template
      class << self
         delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes'

         def first_reverification_notice(email)
           { to: email@gmail.com,
             from: fromemail@gmail.com,
             subject: reverify your email,
             body_html: "Here is some text to reverify, click this link to do so #{verify_link}"}
         end


         def verify_link
            "<a href=#{url_helpers.new_authentication_url(host: ENV['URL_HOST'])}>reverification link</a>"
         end
      end
   end
end
```

When I `rails c` onto my development database and try to execute the method, `first_reverification_notice` I get this error: `NameError: undefined local variable or method url_helpers' for main:Object`

Why do I get this error and how can I avoid it? I've tried executing

`include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` but this doesn't work. What can I try to make this work. Help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: your code invalid (string 4)

Comment: Thank you for your response, IIlya. I addressed the typo in an edit. Aside from that do you have an idea why I would be receiving this error?

Comment: where is closing quote here `delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes` ?

Comment: please update code on how did you included helpers? `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`